# Any possibility to get autocompletion / type-ahead / intellisense in Android XML Files (Eclipse)

Tags: android, xml, autocomplete, intellisense, type-ahead

Is there any way to make Eclipse + Android SDK + ADT Plugin offer some sort of auto-complete in XML files if I hit CTRL+Space when my cursor is in a spot such as the ones marked with an * below.

```
<LinearLayout id* ... lay*>
```

The thing is that I think that the above was actually working already directly after the initial install - even though it of course never worked within style files.

```
<style name="ActionBarWrapper" parent="Fill_Parent.Vertical">
        <item name="android:layout_height">36dp</item>
            <item name="a*"
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an icon in the eclispe toolbar to directly access the "new android xml file" wizard.

Comment: Since this actually solves the problem (that I, as it turned out, kinda created all by myself) I decided to pick this as the correct answer. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use IntelliJ IDEA instead of Eclipse, it has full auto-completion and works well for Android development.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

The Community Edition fully supports Android, and is FREE

Comment: That's a nice idea and I am fully aware of the additional benefits that come along with using IntelliJ but unfortunately that's not really the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The latest ADT plugin (r9) does have partial auto complete feature in the layout xml.
for example, if you type ctrl-spacebar while the cursor is between 2 tags, you get the list of all avaliable tags (views and layouts). If your cursor is inside a tag, you get a list of all avaliable attributes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Thanks for the good advice everybody. Not sure if the following should be an answer or a comment. Going for the answer because comments do not allow enough characters.

After trying out some eclipse plugins (like [Rinzo XML Editor](http://editorxml.sourceforge.net/download.html) ) I found out that it actually worked for some files while it did not work at all for others. After some testing I am now under the impression that there is a difference between creating XML files via...

> New > XML

and

> New > Other > Android > Android XML File

I double checked that even when both files have exactly the same content (xml-version, encoding, namespace etc.) they behave differently with regards to auto-code-completion depending on the way of file-creation. I also checked the file properties but could not make out any significant differences. Obviously it must be something local or some meta stuff I am overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the different behavior is because when you create the file using `"New->XML"` the wizard opens the file using the default associated editor to xml content.

If you create a file using `"New->Other->Android->Android XML File"` I think the wizards tries to open the xml file using a specific xml editor, instead of the one you have configured as default, in this case Rinzo I guess.

In the second case why don't you try finding the xml file in either `"Package Explorer"` view or  `"Navigator"` view, right click on the xml file and selecting Rinzo through the `"Open With"` option.